# What the best way to determine if a string is present in one of 5 array?

Tags: php

I got a marker with a category, say : "luggage" i would like to know what parent categories is luggage to set a specific marker on a map.

I created a top categories list of each category i need to display. Something like :

```
$education = [ "adultedu", "collegecounseling", "collegeuniv", "educationservices", "elementaryschools", "highs|chools", "preschools", "privatetutors", "religiousschools", "specialed", "specialtyschools", "artschools", "cprclasses", "cookingschools", "cosmetology_schools"]
```

I got the same lists for transports, shopping, health etc...

What is the best way to search in which category my keyword is from ?

Comment: It seems you're in the middle of [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - i.e. asking about your `Y` solution. Please, describe whole problem more verbosely.

Comment: Sorry for my english, but it seems that some has understand what i mean :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array and iterate through while using `in_array`:

```
$arrays = array(
    'education' => &$education,
    'transport' => &$transport,
    'shopping'  => &$shopping,
    'health'    => &$health
);

$searchingFor = 'foo';

$searchingForCategory = null;
foreach ($arrays as $category => $array) {
    if (in_array($searchingFor, $array)) {
        $searchingForCategory = $category;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($searchingForCategory); //education / transport / shopping / health / NULL
```

Comment: Seems good, subsidiary question why `&$education`? what is the `&` ?

Comment: @x_vi_r It's a `reference` operator. It means that instead of copying the `$education` array to `$arrays['education']` (so we have 2 arrays, filling up twice the memory) we simply point towards the same point in memory.

Comment: Woo didn't know that ! kool

Comment: @x_vi_r That said, if you work a lot with objects/OOP you should know that these are parsed by reference per default.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check each array with `in_array()` function.

```
 if (in_array('luggage', $education)) {
     // found
 }
```

Also you can add all top categories to one array, lets say `$topCategories` ;)
Then you can check all with simple loop:

```
 $foundInCategory = '';
 foreach ($topCategories as $name => $subCategories) {
     if (in_array('luggage', $subCategories)) {
         $foundInCategory = $name;
         break;
     }
 }
```

It'll add category name in which subcategory was found to variable `$foundInCategory`.